# Yammer api : Get messages by group

Tags: api, rest, yammer

Here are the yammer api docs: http://developer.yammer.com/restapi/

Am I missing something here? How can I get the messages for a specific group? There seems to be a good deal of undocumented functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree the documentation appears lacking.

Maybe:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/<<GROUPID>>.json?access_token=<<ACCESSTOKEN>>"
```

via http://balamurugankailasam.blogspot.com/2012/10/displaying-yammer-feed-private-group-in.html

---

Embeded feeds support this functionailty:

> - feedType – Type of Feed to be displayed: group, topic, user, or Open Graph object
> - feedID – ID of the group, topic, or user feed (not applicable for Open Graph or My Feed)

**Example**

```
<script data-app-id="hyB2pTvrL36Y50py8EWj6A" src="https://assets.yammer.com/platform/yam.js"></script>
<script>
  yam.connect.embedFeed(
      { container: '#embedded-feed',
        network: 'fourleaf.com',
        feedType: 'group',           // can be 'group', 'topic', or 'user'          
        feedId: '123'                // feed ID from the instructions above
  });    
</script>    
<div id="embedded-feed"></div>
```

via http://developer.yammer.com/connect/

Comment: Any luck with this answer?

Comment: oops, sorry for seemingly abandoning this. I got a similar response from somebody in the yammer support network eventually. Marking your answer as correct, the url you provided does work for this

Comment: @AaronBruce Could you post a link to the answer you got in the Yammer support network? Would be interested in what they had to say.

Comment: Sorry, @joweiser, this was two years ago and I don't think I have access to my accounts anymore (I guess Microsoft bought yammer and switched over to some Microsoft account SSO thing?).

Comment: @AaronBruce Thx for the info! I'm already engaged in various conversations over there. API documentation is super sparse, a bit out of date, and apparently they lost one person or maybe more who were responsible for the documentation side of things. Sad state.